# Transform SOAP to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

I'm really stuck on transforming a SOAP request into a usable XML file that I can upload into a Filemaker database. I have been searching for days, but I can't find a solution that works. I have copied a sample of the SOAP request below, and the desired output below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

All I have managed to do so far is generate the content using the follow XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns ="http://www.somedomainename.com">

<xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SOAP request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns0:course_application_list xmlns:ns0="http://au.edu.sydney/schemas/studentcoursemanagement/courseppplication/courseapplicationdetails/1.0">
     <ns0:course_application>
        <ns0:application_form_seqno>01</ns0:application_form_seqno>
        <ns0:course_application_seqno>01</ns0:course_application_seqno>
        <ns0:application_course>MAEDUCAT-03</ns0:application_course>
        <ns0:commence_year>2014</ns0:commence_year>
        <ns0:sid>11223344</ns0:sid>
        <ns0:application_type>I</ns0:application_type>
        <ns0:application_status>AF</ns0:application_status>
        <ns0:decision1>U</ns0:decision1>
</ns0:course_application>
  </ns0:course_application_list>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Desired output XML:

```
 <course_application_list>
 <course_application>
    <application_form_seqno>01</application_form_seqno>
    <course_application_seqno>01</course_application_seqno>
    <application_course>MAEDUCAT-03</application_course>
    <commence_year>2014</commence_year>
    <sid>11223344</sid>
    <application_type>I</application_type>
    <application_status>AF</application_status>
    <decision1>U</decision1>
</course_application>
</course_application_list>
```

Comment: "*I have been searching for days, but I can't find a solution that works.*" Have you considered spending an hour or two actually learning XSLT? Copy and paste will not get you very far. -- "*a usable XML file that I can upload into a Filemaker database.*" Not sure what you mean by "upload". In order to **import** XML  to Filemaker, your output must conform to Filemaker's FMPXMLRESULT schema - the output that you show us is nowhere near that.

Comment: Yeah I have been trying to. It is challenging when the XML contains a SOAP envelope and namespaces. I have found ways to manipulate either of those in XML, but not when they're combined together. I am a business analyst - I've programmed before, but I am not hardcore technical. I am trying to do this as no developers are available.

Comment: Yes you're right about it needed to conform to the schema. I think that would be fine to figure out if i could actually make any changes to the XML. All I can manage to do is extract the data in the attributes.

Comment: You don't need to make any changes to the XML. That's what XSLT does: it transforms the given XML to the target schema. You just need to change your stylesheet to produce the right output. See here for an introduction: http://web.archive.org/web/20101013013430/http://my.advisor.com/doc/12009 --  "*no developers are available*" Beg pardon?

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its original form, since you have - quite correctly - posted a [new question with the new requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429988/transform-soap-to-filemaker-xml-using-xslt).

Answer (score 2):

You need to manage your namespaces appropriately, what you can probably is something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:somedo ="http://au.edu.sydney/schemas/studentcoursemanagement/courseppplication/courseapplicationdetails/1.0"
        exclude-result-prefixes="somedo">

  <!-- This will skip all SOAP-env related elements --> 
  <xsl:template match="soap:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this will copy all elements without the namespace declaration -->
  <xsl:template match="somedo:*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I obtain so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<course_application_list>
        <course_application>
            <application_form_seqno>01</application_form_seqno>
            <course_application_seqno>01</course_application_seqno>
            <application_course>MAEDUCAT-03</application_course>
            <commence_year>2014</commence_year>
            <sid>11223344</sid>
            <application_type>I</application_type>
            <application_status>AF</application_status>
            <decision1>U</decision1>
        </course_application>
    </course_application_list>
```

Comment: Your first and last templates are not doing anything and can be removed.

Comment: @michael.hor257k they don't do anything because there are neither attributes, processing instructions nor comments in input document -- is it what you mean?

Comment: The first one can be removed because there's a built-in template rule to do the same. The last one can be removed because there are no attributes (and they are not likely to want to import PI's or comments into a database).

Comment: I agree -- I kept them because I didn't want to make any assumptions on the XML input format, which is only a sample (I don't know Filemaker at all and I have only basic knowledge regarding SOAP).

Comment: Thanks very much @potame! I have tried doing what you said using an online XSLT tester, and the result produced is:

     01 01 MAEDUCAT-03 2014 11223344 I AF U

... Am I missing something?

Comment: Have modified the namespaces declaration on the root element of the stylesheet?

Comment: Nevermind, it was the testing tool I was using, I have used another and it works. Thanks so much, you are a legend!